# charge_control_end_threshold not writable

Tags: permissions, power-management, battery, battery-charging-threshold

I was trying to put a charging threshold on my laptop (Huawei matebook 13), this functionality works on windows and worked on my previous linux install (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS).
I tried doing the same stuff specified [here](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/how-to-start-battery-charge-threshold-service-on-boot/20305), but I encountered the problem below.
I tried to use
`bash -c echo 25 > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold` even with root, but I always get the same `permission denied` error.

I checked this:

```
e@e:~$ ll /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold \
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 10 11:40 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold

e@e:~$ ll /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0 \
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 10 11:39 /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0 -> ../[redacted]/power_supply/BAT0/
```

so the file should be writable, still it is not. Any suggestion?

- OS: Ubuntu 23.04
- I tried using TLP; it didn't worked (idk what to check)

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure but read althought this is present **charge_control_end_threshold** there are some issue where if **charge_control_start_threshold** is greater than **charge_control_end_threshold** you cannot set it.
I am not sure if your issue is due to this.

For this Huawei devs have provide an option to set both start and end settings at the same time. If you want to set start threshold at 50 and end threshold at 60 you can use this command

```
echo "50 60" | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/huawei-wmi/charge_control_thresholds
```

Alternatively you can use **Battery Health Charging** Gnome extension (if you are using gnome) to control threshold.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5724/battery-health-charging/

It provides a GUI way to set threshold and supports most of the laptop brands on various distro's running gnome.

Another note. Do not set your threshold to 25%. Recomended values by most manufacturer are 50-60 or 70-80, (depending on your usage)